# Can I view seed words of non deterministic wallet?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, non-deterministic-wallet

I have created my Monero wallet long time ago. Today I tried to see my seed and the terminal give me the message "wallet is non-deterministic and have no seed" So do I have to create new wallet or do I have another option?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a seed, you have to make a deterministic wallet. The seed is a representation of your private spend key, and deterministic wallets derive the private view key from it. Therefore, a non deterministic wallet would not be able to restore the private view key from a seed (or it'd have to be twice the size, which is was not done for unknown reasons).

Answer (score 1):

There's no other option. You have to create a new wallet and move your monero there. The scheme used for deterministic wallet means that your mnemonic is the result of encoding your private spend key. So, only the information of the private spend key is "stored" in the mnemonic. The private view key is derived from it.

Considering that in non-deterministic wallet, both private spend and private view keys are independently generated, you can't encode this with the 24 words.